# Why isn't count counting anything?

Tags: php, count

I'm having trouble making a simple count work. Right now 0 is constantly displayed when I run the code and I know it's because I set count to 0. But it should be displaying the number of times "Fizz" is displayed.

I'm sure it's simple but I just can't see what!

```
public function __construct($firstParam, $secondParam, $firstSound = "Fizz", $secondSound = "Buzz", $numbers = 100) {
        $this->firstParam = $firstParam;
        $this->secondParam = $secondParam;
        $this->firstSound = $firstSound;
        $this->secondSound = $secondSound;
        $this->numbers = $numbers;
        $this->numsArray = $numsArray;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        $count = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->numsArray); $i++){
            $val = $this->numsArray[$i];
            if ($val == $this->firstSound) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        $print = "Number of Fizzes: ".$count;
        return $print;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->numsArray = array();
        if ($this->secondParam > $this->firstParam) {
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->numbers; $i++){
                if ($i % $this->firstParam == 0 && $i % $this->secondParam == 0) {
                    $this->numsArray[] = "\n".$this->firstSound.$this->secondSound."\n";
                } elseif ($i % $this->firstParam == 0) {
                    $this->numsArray[] = "\n".$this->firstSound."\n";
                } elseif ($i % $this->secondParam == 0) {
                    $this->numsArray[] = "\n".$this->secondSound."\n";
                } else {
                    $this->numsArray[] = "\n".$i."\n";
                }
                echo $this->numsArray[$i-1];
            }
        } else {
            echo "\n".' First Number Bigger Than Second '."\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: count($this->numsArray) is not evaluating properly.
check its value and tell me what it says.

Comment: is numms array populated with random sounds Fizz and Buzz? If Numsarray does not have any elements with Fizz in it within index 0 to 99 then this will return 0.

Comment: look in the execute function, it's populated with sounds as well as the rest of the numbers. A standard call to it would look like this: $test1 = new FizzBuzz(5, 7, "Fizz", "Buzz", 100);
$test1->execute();

Comment: in execute it is not assigning the values to numsArray[i] also you inject new line characters that will not match the equality you just when checking $val

Comment: It should be, if I run it the output there produces exactly what I want and what you'd expect.

Comment: How should my if statement look then?

Comment: I have attached an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your execute you are not assigning the values to numsArray[i] also you inject new line characters that will not match the equality you just when checking $val. Also I notice you use zero index to check them and index 1 to load it. Change execute to:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $this->numbers; $i++){
   if ($i % $this->firstParam == 0 && $i % $this->secondParam == 0) {
      $this->numsArray[i] = $this->firstSound.$this->secondSound;
   } elseif ($i % $this->firstParam == 0) {
      $this->numsArray[i] = $this->firstSound;
   } elseif ($i % $this->secondParam == 0) {
      $this->numsArray[i] = $this->secondSound;
   } else {
      $this->numsArray[i] = $i;
   }
   echo $this->numsArray[$i];
```

This is a better binary string comparison for php...

```
if (strcmp($val, $this->firstSound) == 0)
```

Comment: This didn't do anything differently, same result as before.

Comment: what does the contents of numsArray look like?
print_r ($this->numsArray);

Comment: [96] => 
Fizz

    [97] => 
97

    [98] => 
98

    [99] => 
Fizz

)      I think it's also the same as before

Comment: other thing I can think of is your string comparison.  edited answer.

Comment: that just outputs the total number of contents in the array, not how many Fizzes there were